# Android image button

Tags: android

I m developing an application where i need to insert **image buttons** inside edit text window.
On clicking particular image button it should get inserted at cursor of edit text.

How can i do this?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: `it should get inserted at` means ??

Comment: like while doing chatting after text where cursor is placed,image button should get inserted there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xyz), null);
```

Or something like `android:drawableRight`  in the layout as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

Comment: But this will place image button at right most of edit text. not at cursor

Comment: I haven't tested it , but setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() this might work to wrap image around the text in it..

Comment: i had tried it earlier...but of no use ..it just sets where it is to be appeared in edit text..not at cursor position

Comment: thanks fr giving time but this was not what i was looking for.I want to insert smileys(image button) after chat text(in edit text)..I needed code for it.